# Running docker image on pivotal cloud foundry

Tags: spring, docker, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I have an application that is running in a docker container. Is it possible to deploy this docker container containing the application in Cloud Foundry without making any changes to the application or container itself?

Comment: What sort of Cloud Foundry set up do you have?  Are you using a hosted CF, deployed your own from open source code, etc?  Based on your comment in the below answer, sounds like you might have multiple ports exposed, is that true?  Or multiple endpoints exposed as different URL paths on the same port?

Comment: We have a private instance of PCF hosted in our internal servers. Yes , the docker instance that I was talking about exposed servlet endpoints on port 8080. These are multiple endpoints running on the same port.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your specific question about whether you will need to make changes to your Docker image or not, here's the relevant info.

- Currently there is no support for mounting volumes or linking containers, but projects to support these use cases are actively in flight, so if your `docker run` workflow normally involves that you will have to wait.
- There is only support for v2 Docker registries, so if your image repository is in a Docker registry with an older API, it won't work.
- There is no support for private repositories (that is, repositories that require a username and password to access the image in the registry).  You can, however, provide your own custom registry and make it only accessible to your CF backend, and then push your image as a public repo to that custom registry.

(Info filtered from [official CF docs site](http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/docker.html#caveats) and [Diego design notes](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/diego-design-notes/blob/master/docker-support.md#docker-deltas))

Answer (score 1):

As discussed on Cloud Foundry's [documentation](https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/concepts/docker.html), you should first enable the `diego_docker` feature flag with the following command:

```
cf enable-feature-flag diego_docker
```

Then use the `cf push` in order to push your docker image. Versions `6.13.0` and later of the CF CLI include native support for pushing a Docker image as a CF app, with the `cf push` command's `-o` or `--docker-image` flags. For example, running:

```
cf push lattice-app -o cloudfoundry/lattice-app
```

will push the image located at `cloudfoundry/lattice-app`. You can also read [here](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/diego-design-notes/blob/master/docker-support.md) for more information about Docker Support in CF + Diego.

Comment: Thanks Ali! Does this mean that I wouldn't have to make changes to the app? The app has number of servlet endpoints.

Comment: Your container does not need to be changed but you should upload your container to a pubic docker registry, since diego does not currently support fetching images from private repositories.